# Index of subgroups in infinite p-group

Tags: p-groups, infinite-groups, maximal-subgroup

If $G$ is a finite $p$-group, it is trivial that every subgroup has index $p^r$ for some integer $r$.
If $G$ is infinite, this is not true as the index can be infinite.

If $G$ is an infinite $p$-group, what is possible to say about $[G:H]$ if :

- $H$ is of finite index ?
- $H$ is maximal and of finite index ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $H$ is of finite index, then this index is a power of $p$.
If $H$ is maximal and of finite index, then this index is $p$.

To see this, let's consider the normal core $N ⊲ G$ of $H$. Then $G/N$ is finite, it is a corollary of Cayley's strong theorem. Moreover, it is also a $p$-group since every element is annihilated by a power of $p$. For every subgroup $W$ of $G$ containing $N$, we have $[G : W] = [G/N : W/N]$. So in particular, $[G : H] = [G/N : H/N]$ is a power of $p$ and by Sylow's theorems there is a subgroup $W/N ⊆ G/N$ containing $H/N$ of index $p$.

If $H$ is only supposed to be maximal, then Tarski's monsters are examples where $H$ doesn't have finite index.